# Should we move all future 3D questions to Blender.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

I know for awhile we have helped 3D questions but when I think about who *could* help the OP **better** I still think that Blender Stack Exchange would  than Graphic Design Stack Exchange.  How do you feel about asking the Blender community to allow us to send all future 3D questions to them.  For awhile there we had one member ask at least once a week a 3DS Max question and after looking not any of them were answered.

I am aware we did have a 3D Stack Site called [3D graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5022/3d-graphics) but it was closed.

There is even a new startup for it: [3D Modeling and Animation](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66353/3d-modeling-and-animation)

Answer (score 2):

I'm all for migrating any worthy *Blender* questions, but I think sending them any and all 3D questions would screw up their ecosystem.

Comment: I see the pros and cons but how would if effect their eco-system versus ours?  They are a 3D platform and 3D professionals visit them more for 3D then people that visit us which could provide a better answer.

Comment: they would just close the questions as offtopic.We could also just declare 3d as part of graphics design. And then accumulate 3dspecialits. Our ambivalence on the subject is the problem

Answer (score -2):

If somebody is asking how to create a '3D' image or effect in a 2D vector design package or Photoshop, then yes, they should *definitely* be directed towards the Blender site (although if they mention Maya over there they will probably be told what fools they are for having wasted all that money ;-).

I spent a couple of years trying to create isometric and perspective images in CorelDraw and Illustrator, before I gave up with the ridiculous inflexibility of it and discovered Blender. Model your scene once, then render out any/all the views you want, with any perspective or pure isometric. It doesn't cost a penny and runs on any platform.

(CSx and Blender user for 8 years)